# Probability of getting 3 at least twice on 4 sided die.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have four sided die with a number on each side $\ (1,2,3,4) $ and I need to calculate the possibility of getting $\ 3 $ at least twice after throwing the die $\ 5$ times.

So I out of the $\ 5 $ times I should pick 2 where $\ 3$ is the outcome and then I have $\ 3 $ throws left to have whatever outcome. so it should be $\ \frac{ {5 \choose 2} \cdot 4^3}{4^5} $

Where am I wrong?

Comment: You're overcounting. Any sequence of throws with three $3$'s, for instance, will be counted three times with your method. It's faster and easier to figure out the probability of exactly zero or exactly one $3$, and then negate that. Note that there is no easy formula for "at least $k$ successes" in a problem like this.

Comment: Oh, right! didn't think about that.. could you confirm for me that the number of possible outcomes with only one three would be $\ {5 \choose 1} \cdot 3^4 $ ?

Comment: Looks right to me.